# Powershell: "adsi" - look up user id given a full name?

Tags: powershell, adsi

I have a list of team members names - in a first_name, last_name format in a CSV.
How can I look up their names in AD using Powershell - so that I can get their domain userids ?

I saw examples where "adsi" was used to look based on domain userid->full-name, but I need to perform this the other way round.

(For instance: [Retrieve current domain user's full name](https://serverfault.com/questions/582696/retrieve-current-domain-users-full-name))

I'm not admin on the domain - just a regular user - and want to avoid installing the Active Directory Libraries if possible (since I would like to share the script with other colleagues also - need minimum pre-reqs)

Comment: Got marked 'off-topic' ?  - I guess it might be a better fit for 'stackoverflow' (general) or 'super user' (maybe?).
(Rhetorical question / note to self)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the User Account property DisplayName is "Firstname Lastname" then the following will do what you're looking for

```
$name = "John Doe"
$search = [adsisearcher]"(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=User)(displayname=$name))"
$search.FindAll() | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Properties
```

Note the userid is known as samAccountName

Comment: Brilliant - works a treat.

Comment: For others reading this: I would suggest examining your own user using this Post : https://serverfault.com/questions/582696/retrieve-current-domain-users-full-name , then use this function to verify the reverse-lookup.

Comment: My Powershell Kung Fu is weak....what's the most concise way of getting *just* the 'samaccountname' back from that list..(I should ask a new question really - but worth an ask....)

Comment: Found this: https://jamesmccaffrey.wordpress.com/2008/10/16/searching-active-directory-with-powershell/

Which suggested the idea of holding the result in a var, which you can de-reference using dot-notation:

$results=$search.FindAll()
$results.properties.samaccountname

Comment: And actually - for my specific example - the 'FindOne()' method is more appropriate. (rather than FindAll())